# Django one-to-many queries

Tags: sql, django

Django newbie here.

I created three models: Band, Album and AlbumType (Live, EP, LP). Album have two foreign keys (from band and albumtype). Ok, so, in the view a make something like this:

```
bandList = Band.objects.all()
```

To retrieve all the bands but I can't figure out how to get all the Albums from a Band in the same view.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default the related objects (through a `ForeignKey` on the other model) are accessible trough `<modelname>_set` zo in this case that is `band.album_set` (note this is a Manager attribute so you will probably use `band.album_set.all()` most of the time).

I personally prefer to give al my `ForeignKey` fields a `related_name` so I can name the attribute on the other model. The next example gives the `Band` the attribute `band.albums`.

```
class Band(models.Model):
    # Band definition

class Album(models.Model):
    band = models.ForeignKey(Band, related_name='albums')
    # Rest of album definition
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be great if you share your models definition. But I hope this helps you:

If you want to retrieve the Albums for a specific band:

```
band = Band.objects.get(...)
band_albums = Album.objects.filter(band=band)
```

That will return the albums for a band.

If you want retrive albums for all the bands:

```
bandList = Band.objects.all().select_related('album_set')
```

This will return the bans as before, but will cache the albums.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really useful. That's help me to understand a lot of Django things.